# AWS CDK task defintion version different from CodePipeline deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I've developed a script using the AWS CDK to deploy an ECS Fargate service. This script deploys the service with a default nginx image and generates Task Definition revision 1.

Furthermore, the script creates a Pipeline that employs an ECR Repo as the source and CodeDeploy for deployment onto Fargate.

Upon pushing the image to ECR, the pipeline is triggered and deploys the image to the service using Task Definition revision 2, which is the expected behavior.

Now, when I need to make a change, such as adjusting the CPU units, I use my CDK. However, the CDK utilizes Task Definition 1 to create Task Definition revision 3, rather than using Task Definition 2. This is not the desired behavior. As a result, my initial nginx docker image is deployed instead of the image of my microservice, causing downtime.

How can I address this issue?